# Atom namespace with php simplexml

Tags: php, namespaces, rss, simplexml, atom-feed

This is my RSS template that I load into my simplexml object. I want to change the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <atom:link href="link" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <title></title>
        <link></link>
        <description></description>
        <lastBuildDate></lastBuildDate>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

I'd like to change the href attribute in atom:link but I have no clue how to access it. I scoured through SO and found a bunch of information on how to access different namespaces but I can't figure out how to apply any of them to this specific example (mostly because I am pretty dense :)

I can modify my link attribute with the line of code below but how would I modify the attribute mentioned above?

```
$rss->channel->link = $rssLink;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$attrs = $rss->channel->children("atom", true)->link->attributes();
$attrs["href"] = "href_value";
```

Example [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/yzA6zD).

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been hammering at this for an hour or so :)

Comment: The link for the example isn't working, but thanks both for the answer and for the way the question was posed. I spent ages trying to get SimpleXml to add a child named 'atom:link' and hadn't realised that one could simply start with it in the template!